# Is there an easy proof of this equation related to simultaneous Pell equations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, elementary-proofs

Working with the famous Baker-Davenport system of simultaneous Pell equations
\begin{align}
  3x^2-2 &= y^2, &
  8x^2-7 &= z^2, \qquad(\star)
\end{align}
I am left, after a series of substitutions and reductions, with the equation
$$
  u(u+1)\left(96u(u+1)+11\right) = v(v+1). \qquad(\dagger)
$$
The point is now to prove that the only solutions with $u \ge 0$ are $u=0$ and $u=5$, yielding, respectively, the two known (and only) solutions $x=1$ and $x=11$ in ($\star$).

Are there any ways of attacking the formulation ($\dagger$), different from those which would naturally be applied to ($\star$), which might lead to a relatively straight-forward proof?

Thanks,
Kieren.

EDIT: For example, by unique factorization of integers, we can write $(v,v+1)=(abc,rst)$ for postive integers $a,b,c,r,s,t$ with $gcd(abc,rst)=gcd(v,v+1)=1$. Now, with appropriate permutation, we can write
\begin{align}
  u &= ar, & u+1 &= bs, & 96u(u+1)+11=ct.
\end{align}
But all methods and manipulations I've tried from that point seem to lead to dead ends.

Comment: Noting for documentation sake that OP posted, and then deleted, another question about these equation recently, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143301/is-there-a-simple-descent-proof-for-the-baker-davenport-simultaneous-pell-equa

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I found soon after I posted that the result was trivial, so I didn't think it worthy of remaining on MO. I did not know (1) that deleted posts are still visible, nor (2) that such documentation was required or expected.

As you can tell from my reputation points and/or profile, I'm fairly new to MO and MSE — are these rules and expectations listed somewhere?

Sorry, Kieren.

Comment: Deleted posts are visible to those with enough points. I don't know that documentation is required, but speaking for myself, I like people posting here to put all their cards on the table.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I'm certainly not trying to hide anything. I just didn't think that deleted observation was worth MO bandwidth, once I saw how trivial it was.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, it's probably no easier: both are looking for integer points
on a genus-$1$ curve.  In fact it's not hard to get from Baker-Davenport
to your equation: multiplying the two equations in $(\star)$ yields
$(3x^2-2)(8x^2-7) = (yz)^2$, and both $x$ and $yz$ must be odd,
so we can write $(x,yz) = (2u+1,2v+1)$, and then subtracting $1$
and dividing by $4$ yields $(\dagger)$.

Comment: Yes, that's my "series of substitutions and reductions". I was (am) hoping that there would be (_e.g._) a factorization approach applicable to ($\dagger$) that isn't applicable to ($\star$) directly.

Comment: [See edit of original post for more thoughts.]